# OAuth2 for REST API with tightly coupled SPA as only client

Tags: rest, security, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a REST API with a tightly coupled SPA as the only client of the mentioned REST API.

Let's say the SPA is available at `myservice.com` and api is under `myservice.com/api`. They're basically one service, just split at code level, and deployed at different root paths.

What I'm using for security right now is OAuth2 with ROPC (username/password) grant type.

Here comes the problem. I keep reading everywhere that ROPC is not secure and should not be used. What should I use then?

My REST API acts as an authorization server but it doesn't have any web interface itself. So any flow involving redirect doesn't really make sense. The SPA and API are so tightly coupled that for an end user they're basically one application. There's no 3rd party.

I could add simple login form to the API available at let's say `myservice.com/login`. But I'm struggling to see the difference that would make.

Security in this application is very important.

**Here are my questions:**

Is using ROPC really dangerous in this scenario?

What would be the perfect way for authentication and authorization?

Or maybe OAuth2 is completely redundant without a third party?

**Technologies used:**

Server: Spring Boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to this can be taken out from [OAuth 2.0 specification (RFC6749)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) itself. It define when ROPC grant is suitable for,

**[4.3.  Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3)**

> The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in
> cases **where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the
> client**, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application.  The authorization server should take special care when
> enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not
> viabl.

According to your explanation, you have tight coupling with SPA and backend. Also you have both authorization server and resource server built as one. This is completely [acceptable implementation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1).

> **The authorization server
> may be the same server as the resource server** or a separate entity.

So what matter now is to clear out why you use OAuth 2.0 in your scenario.

If you are using OAuth 2.0 to obtain tokens, maintain them as defined through OAuth 2.0 specification, then this is completely oaky. But if you are doing this to follow a trend, think twice.

OAuth 2.0 implementation comes with it's own complexity. You have to maintain user identities, maintain tokens and renew them. You are building a complete authorization server by yourself. But this also have some advantages as well.

For example, same authorization server can be used to issue token for future integrations/secondary app. IMO, usage of OAuth 2.0 make integrations easy as it define a protocol for issuing tokens, renew and revoke them.! **But in such integration scenario, may be you will require to use a different grant. Still, your API being authorized on token, you only need to worry about how new integration/application obtain tokens. This is better than using authenticated sessions**

Going back to your questions,

**Q : Is using ROPC really dangerous in this scenario?**

As explained, if there is a correct trust relationship between **client** and **authorization server**, then it is fine. But be mindful about complexity comes with having a **authorization server**.

**Q : What would be the perfect way for authentication and authorization?**

OAuth 2.0 is for **authorization**. You obtain access token and use them to authorize against your protected APIs. From APIs you do a token validation to detect correct access levels/permissions.

If you want **authenticaiton**, then you must use [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html). It is a protocol extended from OAuth 2.0. And allows your application to authenticate the end user based on ID Token. You can use ROPC grant to obtain an ID token.!

**Q : Or maybe OAuth2 is completely redundant without a third party?**

Not necessarily. It allows you to design your APIs in a modern, standard way. Who know what future hold (again the integration scenario). Following a protocol allows that easy.

Only advice, follow specifications closely. Do not invent your own protocol/adaptation. It makes things harder to maintain.

Comment: @dur IMO main point highlighted in specification is the line *where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the client*. Device OS or privileged app are some examples. In OP's scenario, SPA is owned by backend API (same org). It is all about trust relationship as I have highlighted

Comment: Regarding second point, using OAuth tokens to communicate with API is better than using basic auth. Of course one could use Session instead, which get authenticated after the log in. But as I have highlighted, it can make future integrations difficult. So if OP wants flexibility and OP is not trying to follow a trend (ex- adapt OAuth simply because a buzz word) then ROPC is okay for this specific scenario.

Comment: Thanks. I have one followup question. If I wanted to add some other security measure for token obtainment e.g. recaptcha. Would that be compatible with the protocol? Or should I in that case drop OAuth and create own token obtainment solution? Can't seem to find answer to that.

Comment: @TuanPham well that's another benefit you get from OAuth. Since you authenticate end user at authorization server, your two factor authentication get implemented at authorization server. Your application do not have to worry about such implementation. And this is something independent of protocol but related to how you choose end user authentication

Comment: Yes, but as I said in question, at the authorization server I'm using OAuth protocol for token obtainment. Remember that my application and my application server are basically one. OAuth here is merely a token obtainment protocol. Can I somehow add some additional security layer like captcha to that token obtainment process?

Comment: @TuanPham now I get your second question. Well in your case, you are using ROPC grant. It require your client to obtain credentials from end user. In that, your application has to enable such two factor authentication functionality. But if you are using a grant that involves authorization server, then implementation moves to authorization server end. Sorry about the confusion with my  previous comment

Answer (score 4):

> Is using ROPC really dangerous in this scenario?

No, not really providing:

a) You don't store a user's password - maybe only use it to get the initial access and refresh token - although that could be tricky with an SPA.

b) Your SPA client and the resource API are owned by you, so you don't need the user to consent to specific scoped access for the SPA.

> What would be the perfect way for authentication and authorization?

It depends on lots of things. Not enough info to try to answer that. OAuth2.0 (with a probably implemented Authorisation server) is a pretty good way for the example you have here.

> Or maybe OAuth2 is completely redundant without a third party?

If other applications will use your API in time then OAuth2.0 is probably a good call. Otherwise you could probably use a more simple solution e.g. session cookies as all sits on same domain.